# What are the parallels for the adverb 'visually' when talking about hearing and smelling?

Tags: word-request

What are the **parallels** for the adverb '**visually**' when talking about hearing and smelling?

Here are some examples:

> I can explain it to you more **visually**. (for eyes)
>
> I can explain it to you more -? - (for ear).
>
> They are sounds more masculine, -?- (for ear)
>
> I can explain it to you more -?- (for nose).
>
> It can be more understood, -?- (for nose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant adjectives and adverbs below

> hearing ⟹ auditory ⟹ **auditorily** or **auditorially**
>
> smell ⟹ olfactory ⟹ **olfactorily**

Note that neither of these adverbs [seems to be in common use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=auditory%2Cauditorily%2C%20olfactory%2C%20olfactorily&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) (and in fact my online dictionary marks them as incorrect spelling).  You may be better off rephrasing the sentence to use the adjectives.

> I can better explain it to you through **auditory** cues.

Also, this kind of use sounds somewhat *clinical*, like a scientific researcher. In common conversation it would sound more natural to say:

> You will better understand it if you **listen** to it.
>
> If you **smell** it, you'll understand.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this link doesn't work. It's only to me?

Comment: @Perplexedfolks  fixed it.  It's just an Ngram chart showing relative use.